# change order on odd ng-repeat in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat that on every even number I want to alternate the inner li elements?

room img
        {{room}}

in the end the repeat will look like this

```
<li class="room-row" ng-repeat="room in [1,2,3,4]"> 
  <ul class="room-row-wrapper list-unstyled">
    <!-- !!!!! odd normal !!! -->
    <li class="room-tout">room img</li>
    <li class="room-tout"><a ui-sref="main.roomID">{{room}}</a></li>
  </ul>
 <ul class="room-row-wrapper list-unstyled">
    <!-- !!!!! even reverse !!! -->

    <li class="room-tout"><a ui-sref="main.roomID">{{room}}</a></li>
    <li class="room-tout">room img</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li class="room-row" ng-repeat="room in [1,2,3,4]"> 
  <ul class="room-row-wrapper list-unstyled" ng-if="$odd">
    <!-- !!!!! odd normal !!! -->
    <li class="room-tout">room img</li>
    <li class="room-tout"><a ui-sref="main.roomID">{{room}}</a></li>
  </ul>
 <ul class="room-row-wrapper list-unstyled"  ng-if="$even">
    <!-- !!!!! even reverse !!! -->

    <li class="room-tout"><a ui-sref="main.roomID">{{room}}</a></li>
    <li class="room-tout">room img</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```